# Android - Slide to navigate between activities/listview items

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm working on a beginner Android project and has a ListView with a long list of items. I would like to be able to slide to the left to go to the next Activity or slide to the right to  go to the previous activity instead of always hitting the back button to view the entire list again.

Can anyone help me with a link to read on what I'm trying to do? I've already searched for the past two days but it seems I'm using the wrong search terms so I've been reading things I don't really need.

Thanks

Comment: viewpager is what you want

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to go about this is to use fragments with a viewpager:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html